# most efficient query to get the first and last record id in a large dataset

Tags: t-sql

I need to write a query against a large dataset to get the first and last record id, plus the first record created time. The sample of the data is as following:
[image]

In the above case, if the category "Blue" is passed into the query as parameter, I will expect to return "A12, 13:00, E66" as the result of the query.
I can using aggregate function to get the max and min time from the dataset, and join to get the first and last record. But just wondering whehter there is a more effecient way to achieve the same output?

Comment: How large is your dataset? Do you have indexes on any of the columns?

Comment: you can do the same but on id

Comment: you can also use cursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice would be to try to reduce the number of scan/seek operations by comparing execution plans and to place indexes on the categoryID (for lookup) and time (for sorting) columns.

If you have SQL Server 2008 or later, you could use the following, which requires two scans/seeks:

```
Declare @CategoryID As Varchar(16)

Set @CategoryID = 'Blue'

Select
    First_Record.RecordID,
    First_Record.CreatedTime,
    Last_Record.RecordID
From
       (
          Select Top 1
             RecordID,
             CreatedTime
          From
             <Table>
          Where
             CategoryID = @CategoryID
          Order By
             CreatedTime Asc
       ) First_Record
    Cross Apply
       (
          Select Top 1
             RecordID
          From
             <Table>
          Where
             CategoryID = @CategoryID
          Order By
             CreatedTime Desc
       ) Last_Record
```

If you have SQL Server 2012 or later, you could write the following, which requires only one scan/seek:

```
Select Top 1
    First_Value(RecordID) Over (Partition By CategoryID Order By CreatedTime Asc),
    First_Value(CreatedTime) Over (Partition By CategoryID Order By CreatedTime Asc),
    First_Value(RecordID) Over (Partition By CategoryID Order By CreatedTime Desc)
From
    <Table>
Where
    CategoryID = @CategoryID
```